# How to host jupyter notebook on Azure(ubuntu) VM and make available across the network

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook

I have configure Azure VM ubuntu 18.04

- I have installed Anaconda in VM

I need to start jupyter-notebook on the VM and has to enable across the network. Below is the procedure I have done, but jupyter-notebook is not opening

1. jupyter notebook --generate-config

2.vim /home/Nons/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
   added 2  lines

*c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*' #allow all origins

*c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0' # listen on all IPs

3.sudo ufw allow 8888

4.jupyter-notebook password(optional)

When I started the jupyter-notebook --ip 40.xx.xx.xx Error thrown `"OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address`
"

When I started  jupyter-notebook `[W 11:43:33.495 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect to the notebook from another computer, or over the internet, you need to configure the notebook server to listen on all network interfaces. It's unnecessary to set the IP address with the public IP of the VM, just set it with *:

```
jupyter notebook --ip=*
```

And then create the NSG unbound rule to allow the port 8888.

Comment: @Nons Any other errors do you get? The only one? And do you try to start it without the parameter --ip?

Comment: for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Comment: @Nons It makes no sense. How do you install the Jupyter Notebook? I can access it through the Internet after installation.

Comment: I have azure VM, I have installed anaconda in my VM after that i have enabled port number 8888, and edit the config.py of jupyter file and run jupyter notebook --ip=*

Comment: @Nons Which document do you follow? I follow the steps [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-jupyter-notebook-with-python-3-on-ubuntu-18-04).